# Complex number z satisfies both the inequality $|z-ai|=a+4$ and the inequality $|z-2|<1$

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

The number of integral values of $a$ for which at least one complex number z satisfies both the inequality $|z-ai|=a+4$ and the inequality $|z-2|<1$.

I supposed $z=x+iy$ and put in both equations,

$|x+iy-ai|=a+4\Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+(y-a)^2}=a+4$
$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-2ya+a^2=a^2+8a+16...(1)$

$|x+iy-2|<1\Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}<1.....(2) $

$\Rightarrow (x-2)^2+y^2<1$

$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-4x+4<1......(2)$

How will i solve further to get integer values of $a$?

Comment: What exactly is the first inequality?

Answer (score 2):

HINT....Assuming $a$ is real, for a geometrical interpretation: the first equation represent the point on a circle centre $(0,a)$ and radius $a+4$, and the second one represents the points inside the circle centre$(2,0)$, radius $1$

Comment: The OP was asking for a geometrical interpretation

Comment: What does Nop mean? I am just answering the last part of the question, not the whole question.

Comment: Ok, +1 anyway. Let delete our meaningless discussion)

Comment: @DavidQuinn,Should i solve $a+3<\sqrt{2^2+a^2}<a+5$ to get desired answer.

Comment: Yes. I assume you deduced that from the diagram.

Comment: But i am still not reaching the answer,

Comment: Solve these subject to the condition that $a+4>0$

Comment: ...but you need to clarify what the first inequality is meant to be, or is  it an equation as posted?

Comment: @DavidQuinn,It is an equation,Sir,as posted.